# Bluemix DevOps Editor Syntax Error Marker

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, devops

I'm new in Bluemix DevOps. I created an application based on the SDK for node.js.

I modified an HTML source to test a simple application. My application is working well. But I don't know why below errors is displayed.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: I'm afraid we're going to need a translation on that error, I have no idea what it is saying. StackOverflow is an English site, there are sub sites that deal with other languages, if you wish to check

Comment: I cannot change the language mode of editor to English. So, the error means " '$' is not defined. ".

Comment: It's complaining because it doesn't understand the jQuery notation, I can see you've posted a jQuery library at the top of the screen. Can you confirm your IDE knows about jQuery? I've not used Bluemix DevOps, but I'd assume there is a setting somewhere to specify you are using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If everything is actually working fine, it might be that jQuery isn't a part of your ESLint environment.

Does adding `/*eslint-env jquery */` before the function that uses jQuery fix this?

edit: Additionally, is there an option when you click on the error to add that declaration to your file?